# Why each function may be computed with circuit with 2^n gates?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, circuits

> Why each function may be computed with circuit with 2^n gates ?

I am trying to understand this thing, but I can't. In particular why function constant $1$ requires $2^n$ gates. For me, it should be simple to return $1$ regardless of input.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the statement is that each function can be computed with *at most* $2^n$ gates; it doesn't anything about the *minimal* number of gates needed to compute any function.

That said, you can always add dummy gates to increase the number of gates in your circuit without changing the function it computes. For example, you can replace one of the inputs $x_i$ to $x_i \lor x_i$ to increase the number of gates by 1.

Comment: but I don't still understand it. I know that id does mean: *with $2^n$ gates we can compute each function* (I understand that sometimes this number of gates is overkill). However, can you explain me why function constantly equals to $1$ requires $2^n$ gates?

Comment: It doesn't require $2^n$ gates. that's your (wrong) interpretation of the statement. What the statement was intended to mean is that every function on $n$ inputs can be computed by a circuit containing *at most* $2^n$ gates.

Comment: Maybe you could give me some intuition why it holds ?

Comment: You can get a circuit of size $O(2^n n)$ computing a given function on $n$ bits using the CNF or DNF form of the function (indeed, this results in a circuit whose underlying graph is a tree, i.e., a formula). It turns out that you can slightly improve this trivial construction – in fact, every $n$-bit function has a circuit of size $O(2^n/n)$.

Comment: So you represent function as `CNF` formula. I know that for `CNF` formula it is easy to draw a tree. But why using `CNF` forces $O(2^nn)$ gates I don't understand.

Comment: It doesn't "force" anything. You can implement any CNF using $O(n2^n)$ gates. It's a nice exercise. Note that big O is only an *upper bound*.

Comment: Yes, any CNF I can. However, what about expressing function in CNF ?

Comment: Every function can be expressed in CNF. After all, it's a normal form.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to express $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ in CNF using not more than $2^n$ gates

Comment: I only promised an upper bound of $O(n2^n)$. To get $O(2^n)$ you will need to do something smarter.

Comment: Ok, $O(n2^n)$ is ok, what about it ?

Comment: Ok, I managed to invent how to do it with $O(n2^n)$ gates - it was easy. What about $O(2^n)$

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot function as your personal tutor. You can find the answer in textbooks, for example Jukna's.

Comment: The full title of book ?\

Comment: Boolean function complexity.